# Selecting rows with different rowSums conditions

Tags: r

I'm trying to select create a new df 'Z' out of a df in which for columns 9, 10,11,1,2,4,5 there are less than 3 NA's, and for columns 3,6,7,8,12,13,14 there are exactly 7 NA's. I'm using this code

`Z <- df[c(rowSums(is.na(df[, c(9:11,1,2,4,5)]) < 3)) & (rowSums(is.na(df[, c(6:8,12:14,3)]) == 7)),]`

However, as output I'm getting an empty df with only the 14 column names. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data pls? It would help debugging your command.

Comment: Are there any columns that satisfy that condition in your data?

Comment: @Arna I have provided and answer which I think works, please check it with your original data and, if it works, remember to accept the post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply had some braces in the wrong place

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[, c(9:11,1,2,4,5)])) < 3 & rowSums(is.na(df[, c(6:8,12:14,3)])) == 7,]
```

To help make your code clearer for yourself when debugging try to spread across lines with indentation or spacing your code - here's what I wrote

```
df[
  rowSums( is.na( df[, c(9:11, 1, 2, 4, 5)] ) ) <  3 & 
  rowSums( is.na( df[,    c(6:8, 12:14, 3)] ) ) == 7, ]
```

Compared to yours, spacing helps show the mistake(s)

```
df[
  c(
     rowSums( is.na( df[, c(9:11, 1, 2, 4, 5)] ) <  3 ) ) & 
    (rowSums( is.na( df[,    c(6:8, 12:14, 3)] ) == 7 ) ), ]
```

---

Tested using

```
df <- data.frame(NA,2,NA,4,5,NA,NA,NA,9,10,11,NA,NA,NA)
```